# Reconnect web socket [Haskell]

Tags: haskell, websocket

I am using the `wuss` library ( a wrapper around `websockets`) to create a websocket connection. How would one create loop to reconnect if for whatever reason the web socket disconnects?

```
ws :: ClientApp ()
ws connection = do
    putStrLn "Connected!"

    sendTextData connection msgSubscribe -- defined elsewhere

    let loop = do 
        message <- receiveData connection
        print (message)
        loop

    loop
    sendClose connection (pack "Bye!")

main :: IO ()
main = runSecureClient "ws.kraken.com" 443 "/" ws -- retry at this point?
```

Answer (score 2):

How to "retry" is protocol dependent. If you literally just want to retry from start when there's a connection failure you could just do

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Control.Exception (catch)

-- ...
-- the rest of your code
-- ...

retryOnFailure ws = runSecureClient "ws.kraken.com" 443 "/" ws
  `catch` (\e -> 
     if e == ConnectionClosed
     then retryOnFailure ws
     else return ())
```

but note that this is a "dumb" retry in that it'll literally just start over from scratch if the remote connection is closed unexpectedly (expected closes will lead to the program ending). If you want to maintain any sort of state or anything like that you'll have to figure out how to do that for whatever protocol you're following, but this should be enough if you're just listening for data over some flaky connection.